# elements in array or vector

Tags: arrays, r, select, vector

I have a vector contains repeated values :

v= "3,600"    "3,600"        "3,600"        "3,600"      "3,600"    "3,600"        "3,600"        "3,600"        "3,400"        "3,400"   "3,400"    "3,600"        "3,600"        "3,600"

What is a proper way to find which element do I have, How many are the same and where they are ?
I want an output like :

```
var1:"3,600" rep : 11 position: 1:8, 12:14
var2:"3,400" rep : 3  position: 9:11
```

Comment: This question is a bit broad. `table` will get you the count and the levels. `sapply(unique(v), function(x) which(x == v))` will get positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `split`

```
lst <- split(seq_along(v), v)
lengths(lst)
#   3,400 3,600 
#    3    11
```

---

If we need an output as showed in the OP's post

```
library(data.table)
data.table(v, i = seq_along(v))[, .(var = v[1], rep = .N,
  position = paste(i[1], i[.N], sep=":")) , .(rleid(v))
     ][, .(rep=sum(rep), position = toString(position)), var]
#     var rep   position
#1: 3,600  11 1:8, 12:14
#2: 3,400   3       9:11
```

#### data

```
v <- c("3,600", "3,600", "3,600", "3,600", "3,600", "3,600", "3,600", 
 "3,600", "3,400", "3,400", "3,400", "3,600", "3,600", "3,600"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sapply(unique(v), function(x){
    temp = which((x == v))
    data.frame(variable = x,
            rep = sum(x == v),
            position = paste(sapply(split(temp ,cumsum(c(1, diff(temp)!=1))), function(y)
                paste(range(y), collapse = ":")), collapse = ", "),
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    })
#         3,600        3,400  
#variable "3,600"      "3,400"
#rep      11           3      
#position "1:8, 12:14" "9:11"
```